# How to attach image to email on Android emailIntent

Tags: java, android

To send the email the method for the button is;

```
public void buttonSendEmailClicked(View view) {

        File file = saveFileToShare();
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        emailIntent.setType("application/image");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{}); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Check Out MyPic"); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Taken With Android!");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), interstitial_request);
    
    }
```

The `saveFileToShare` element is this;

```
public File saveFileToShare() {
            try 
            {               
                File fileImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "/DCIM/Camera/attachment.png");
                if(!fileImage.exists())
                {
                    fileImage.delete();
                }
                editorImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = editorImage.getDrawingCache();
                fileImage.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileImage);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);                                        
                ostream.close();
                editorImage.invalidate();
                editorImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                
                return fileImage;

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.print(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
     }
```

Saving the image works fine, the save code is;

```
public void buttonSaveImageClicked(View view) throws IOException {
        editorImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = editorImage.getDrawingCache();
        SaveLayoutToFile saveImage = new SaveLayoutToFile(this, bitmap, editorImage);
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "/DCIM/Camera/wonkydog";
        saveImage.execute(filePath);
    }
```

I need to set the email code to grab the image and attach to email.

At the moment when I press the email button it just returns to the title screen without doing anything else.

If I comment out this line

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Then it opens the mail send dialogue, but without attachment of course...

Comment: I think it is related to content providers. I'm not sure but you may want to check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, rather than using the `emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));`

I replaced it with;
   `emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(EditorActivity.this, "com.myapp.myappname.provider", file));`

It now works correctly!